# Events bundle for symfony2

Tags: events, symfony, bundle

I'm searching for some bundle that can handle events (like facebook parties, birthdays or any other activity) that can make them public or private.

Is there some bundle that meet that needs?

Comment: Probably.  Where have you looked?

Comment: knpbundles, friends of symfony and all trusty google

Comment: As the answer below suggest, use the search function at KNP.  This one might work as well: https://github.com/IDCI-Consulting/SimpleScheduleBundle#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KNPBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) is a good source for Symfony2 bundle listings/information.

A quick [search for events](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=event) shows a bunch of options.